# How to get the begining of a string that contains a word that belongs to an array?

Tags: regex, swift

Given a list of words (and their plurals) to look for:

```
let array = ["\\b(ab+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(cd+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(ef+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(gh+?)(s\\b|\\b)"]
```

This is short for:

```
let words = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
let array = words + words.map {$0 + "s"}
```

I want to get all the words from a sentence. Starting from the beginning of the string, ***up to the last word that satisfies the regular expression***. Each element from `array` or its plural form should match (by adding "s", *ies* plurals aren't taken into consideration) :

for example:

```
let string_1 = "abc ab def cds ghi jkl bs mno" // should get "abc ab def cds"
let string_2 = "abc ghs def" // should get "abc ghs"
let string_3 = "abc ab def bc ghi" // should get "abc ab"
let string_4 = "abc def" // should get "" or nil
```

My current idea is:

```
let words = string_1.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
let lastOccurrence: (Int, String)? = words.enumerated().reversed().first(where: { (index, value) in
    if let _ = restOfSentence.range(of: value, options: .regularExpression) {
        return true
    }
    return false
})

if let l_o = lastOccurrence {
    let matchingWordsArray = words[0...l_o.0]
    let matchingWords = matchingWordsArray.joined(separator: " ")
    print(matchingWords)
}
```

Breaking a sentence into words and then joining them seems expensive to me.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may form a regex like `let pat = "^[abcd]{1,4}s?\\b.*\\b[abcd]{1,4}s?\\b"`. If `"a"`, etc. are multicharacter words, you'd have to use grouping: `^(?:a|b|c|d){1,4}s?\b.*\b(?:a|b|c|d){1,4}s?\b`. But it is not clear if you want to allow matching things like `aaa`. It might turn out that a regex approach is not the best after all.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to match whole words

Comment: Your regex does not match `abc` in `string_1`. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @OOPer *abc* shouldn't match. Only *ab* or *abs* should. The given regex is just an example that accepts a word in singular and plural forms.

Comment: You'd better update the example. Many regex experts can answer your question if your intention is clear enough. It's not clear as your question is inconsistent.

Comment: @OOPer What's not clear about? I'm looking for a faster way to find the last word in a sentence (singular or plural) that is part of a list of words to look for, then return all the words in the sentense up to that last match. Suppose we are looking for the `cat`and `dog`. Given this sentence *You like your dog, and cats in general*. The part that the parser is interested in would be *You like your dog and cats*

Comment: Your example says `abc` should be included in the result, but you say _abc_ shouldn't match. How can readers find which would be the actual result to generate? **Please do update the example as what you exactly want to get**, if you really want to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: @OOPer I've edited the question. Do read carefully the part *Starting from the beginning of the string, up to the last word that satisfies the regular expression.*

Comment: Do read carefully what you write in **for example:**.

Comment: @OOPer Yes the examples are correct.

Comment: Then please explain why `abc` is included in the example, which you say _shouldn't match_.

Comment: @OOPer In the example `string_4 = "abc def"`we can't find neither word *ab* nor *abs*. So there shouldn't be any match

Comment: Please explain why `abc` is included in the results of `string_1`, `string_2` and `string_3`, where you clearly stated **_abc_ shouldn't match**.

Comment: When there is a match, we return all the words from the beginning up to the last match

Comment: Do you mean if any part of a word matches, you want to get the whole word?

Comment: I'm not sure why are you confused, because I feel like I'm repeating myself. The idea is finding the last word in a sentence that matches a regex. In this case we are trying to look for a set of words (and there plural), IF any is found then return From the beginning up to the last match. The code above already works. I'm looking for possible optimizations.

Comment: _finding the last word in a sentence that matches a regex_, this is the most important thing you should include into your question. You mean that other words than the last matching word, the regex array or `words` has no effect. I have no time to write an answer. So I just recommend you to update your question. If you make your question clear enough, someone can answer it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NSRegularExpression (although I find its Swift implementation is annoyingly full of old NSRange/NSString dependencies):

```
let string_1 = "abc ab def cds ghi jkl bs mno" // should get "abc ab def cds"
let string_2 = "abc ghs def" // should get "abc ghs"
let string_3 = "abc ab def bc ghi" // should get "abc ab"
let string_4 = "abc def" // should get "" or nil


let array = ["\\b(ab+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(cd+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(ef+?)(s\\b|\\b)", "\\b(gh+?)(s\\b|\\b)"]

func matchingWords(_ string:String, patterns:[String]) -> String
{
   let anyPattern = patterns.map{"("+$0+")"}.joined(separator:"|")

   let string = NSString(string:string)
   let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0,string.length)

   if let regEx     = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern:anyPattern, options:.caseInsensitive),
      let lastRange = regEx.matches(in:string as String, range:fullRange).last?.range
   {
     return string.substring(to: lastRange.location + lastRange.length)
   }

   return ""
}

print( matchingWords( string_1, patterns:array) ) // abc ab def cds
print( matchingWords( string_2, patterns:array) ) // abc gh
print( matchingWords( string_3, patterns:array) ) // abc ab
print( matchingWords( string_4, patterns:array) ) // <empty string>
```

Comment: My solution is still faster on a large number of strings